# How to tell if a device associated with an Android BluetoothGatt object is connected?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

The [documentation for `BluetoothGatt`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html) indicates methods for connecting and disconnecting, but has no methods to indicate if a device is currently connected or not. The iOS analog that I'm looking for would be [`CBPeripheral.state`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1519113-state).

Do I have to track the connection station myself via the `BluetoothGattCallback` methods or is there a method I can call for this?